# Regex to put quotes around every word followed by colon

Tags: php, json, regex, object-literal

I want to put quotes around every word expressing a definition. All words must do so by a trailing colon.

For example:

```
def1: "some explanation"
def2: "other explanation"
```

Must be transformed to

```
"def1": "some explanation"
"def2": "other explanation"
```

How do I write this with preg_replace in PHP ?

I have this:

```
preg_replace('/\b:/i', '"$0"', 'def1: "some explanation"')
```

But it only enquotes the colon, not the word:

```
key":" "value"
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if one help you :)

Comment: see my answer it may help you to replace all occurance

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution :

```
preg_replace('/([^:]*):/i', '"$1" :', 'def1: "some explanation"');
```

I've replace your regexp by `[^:]*`, which means all caracter except `:`
and then I get it by using `()`, which will be in `$1`.
I then rewrite `$1` with the quotes and add the `:` which had been removed.

Edit : Loop on each line and apply the preg_replace, and that will do the trick.

http://ideone.com/9qp8Hv

Comment: It works for only one entry , add more entries in same line and test again :) https://eval.in/767366 and https://eval.in/767370

Comment: Just need to apply this to each line ;)

Comment: I agree but you need to specify it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern will be always like same as you show in example i.e. 3 character and 1 digit (i.e. def1, def2, def3 and so on) then you can use below pattern:

```
echo preg_replace('/\w+\d{1}/', '"$0"', 'def1: "some explanation" def2: "other explanation"');
```

output:

```
"def1": "some explanation" "def2": "other explanation"
```

Another solution which may have digit or character:

```
echo preg_replace('/\w+(?=:)/', '"$0"', 'def1: "some explanation" def2: "other explanation" def3: "other explanation" defz: "other explanation"');
```

Output:

```
"def1": "some explanation" "def2": "other explanation" "def3": "other explanation" "defz": "other explanation"
```

Explaination of above solution:

```
\w Word. Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
+ Plus. Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
(?= Positive lookahead. Matches a group after the main expression without including it in the result.
: Character. Matches a ":" character (char code 58).
)
```

Both solution will replace all occurance.